# How do i make something inside .html() clickable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i am trying to make the "item 1" be a link. would appreciate any help.

```
   $(document).on('pagecontainerbeforehide','body', function(event, ui){ 
    if (ui.nextPage.attr('id') == "bookmarks"){

        if( $("#bookmark1").is(":checked")){ 

            $("#bookmark-content").html("item 1 ");

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround it with a tag (a `<span>` would work) and then.

```
$("#bookmark-content").find(elementSelectorYouJustCreated).on('click', function(e){ /*do stuff*/ });
```

Or you could save the lookup...

```
if( $("#bookmark1").is(":checked")){
    var $item1 = $('<span>').text("item 1 ");
    $item1.on('click', function(e){ /*do stuff*/ });
    $("#bookmark-content").empty().append($item1);
}
```